# Monitor dask-xarray performance

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I have the following basic code which (I thought) should set up xarray to use a LocalCluster.

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client("tcp://127.0.0.1:46573") # this points to a LocalCluster

import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('*.nc', combine='by_coords') # Uses dask to defer actually loading data
```

I now launch some task which also completes with no issues:

```
(ds.mean('time').mean('longitude')**10).compute()
```

1. I noticed that the tabs for the Task graph, Workers, or Task stream (among others) in the dask-labextension for my LocalCluster remain empty. Shouldn't there be some sort of progress displayed while the computation is running?
2. Which leads me to wonder, how do I tell xarray to explicitly use this cluster? Or is `Client` a singleton such that xarray only ever has one instance to use anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Dask Client it automatically registers itself as the default way to run Dask computations.

You can check to see if an object is a Dask collection with the `dask.is_dask_collection` function.  As you say, I believe that `xr.open_mfdataset` uses Dask by default, but this would be a good way to check.

As to why you're not seeing anything on the dashboard, I unfortunately don't know enough about your situation to be able to help you there.

Comment: Thank you! As for the dashboard (where I see *some* things, just not everything I'd thought I would see), I will try to narrow it down before asking for further help.